# What mitigation can I take for CVE-2020-0022 (aka BlueFrag)?

Tags: updates, security, vulnerability

A vulnerability, [CVE-2020-0022](https://insinuator.net/2020/02/critical-bluetooth-vulnerability-in-android-cve-2020-0022/), was recently announced in some versions of Android. My phone, a Sony Xperia XA2, does not *yet* have an update available.

What should I do in the meantime?

The report suggests "Only enable Bluetooth if strictly necessary". Is it sufficient to disable by tapping the button on the "swipe-down" panel or does it require a deeper configuration change?

[image: Swipe-Down panel with Bluetooth disabled]

The report also suggests "Keep your device non-discoverable". Is it perhaps sufficient to leave discoverability switched off until an update is available? If leaving discoverability switched off was not sufficient mitigation, why would the report even mention it?

Comment: AFAIR "non-discoverable" just means that the device name ist not sent, but if there is Bluetooth traffic your device is visible to any scanner by it's MAC address. The MAC is everything you need if you want to send data to a device (or attack it).